# function field of $zy^2 - x^3$ in the plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am interested in understanding the connection between abstract curves and smooth projective curves. So I looked at a simple example $zy^2 - x^3$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. The function field can be computed on affine opens and it doesn't matter which one you pick:

$z=1$ gives $k(x,\sqrt{x^3})$ while $y=1$ gives $k(x)$ and finally $x=1$ gives $k(y)$. Clearly $k(x)$ and $k(y)$ are the same or isomorphic but $k(x,\sqrt{x^3})$ bothers me. When I take all the dvr's in $k(x,\sqrt{x^3})$ and $k(x)$ and put a topology on them, do I really get the same smooth curve? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's comforting to write down a way in which this first field is isomorphic to the second. The root notation makes me nervous so let's write $K = k(x)[y]/(y^2-x^3)$ and then $\bar{y}$ for the image of $y$ here. Using the relation one finds $(\bar{y}/x)^2 = x$; it then follows that $K = k(\bar{y}/x)$ and that this element $\bar{y}/x$ is transcendental over $k$.

Of course there should be a way of identifying these fields "along" the cuspidal cubic and in fact that's what I've done algebraically; moreover there's a geometric reason for why $\bar{y}/x$ "works" and one ought to be able to "see" the birational map between this curve and $\mathbb{P}^1$. It should also be made clear why you get a field that isn't so funky when looking at $\{x\neq0\}$. I might update this later but it's good for you to play around with it.

It might also be interesting to know [Lüroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem).